# Change the width of the post's/page's content for GitHub pages using Dinky Theme

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I am using the [Dinky theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky) for my GitHub Pages. Is there an easy way to change the width of the post's/page's content? The default width of the content is too narrow for me. I think a small change in [_layouts](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky/blob/master/_layouts/default.html) HTML file at the line

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

or a small change to `_sass/jekyll-theme-dinky.scss`

will serve the purpose but I am not sure.

My initial survey of this repository suggests that a small combination of changes to one of these lines should help but s far I am unsuccessful.

[L30](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky/blob/d7df40f19d675a27f880408e4a371e33d904aebc/_sass/jekyll-theme-dinky.scss#L30), [L212](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky/blob/d7df40f19d675a27f880408e4a371e33d904aebc/_sass/jekyll-theme-dinky.scss#L212), [L323](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky/blob/d7df40f19d675a27f880408e4a371e33d904aebc/_sass/jekyll-theme-dinky.scss#L323), [L339](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky/blob/d7df40f19d675a27f880408e4a371e33d904aebc/_sass/jekyll-theme-dinky.scss#L339), [L363](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky/blob/d7df40f19d675a27f880408e4a371e33d904aebc/_sass/jekyll-theme-dinky.scss#L363), [L378](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky/blob/d7df40f19d675a27f880408e4a371e33d904aebc/_sass/jekyll-theme-dinky.scss#L378) and [L429](https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky/blob/d7df40f19d675a27f880408e4a371e33d904aebc/_sass/jekyll-theme-dinky.scss#L420)

Thankyou for any help.